# jQuery dynamic tabs with more menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm creating a menu with more option.

Expected behaviour is something similar to what Pinterest is using for their tabs. Recorded a video from their website, can be found below. I'm trying to mimic the behaivour, not the visual.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBmIK.jpg

---

So far this is what managed to do. Links under more menu is disappearing every time I select something.

```js
var moreMenu = $(".cat-links a").slice(3);
$(".cat-links a").slice(3).remove();
$('.more-list').append(moreMenu);

$(".more-menu .more").click(function(){
  $(".more-list").toggleClass("open");
});

$(".more-list a").click(function(){
  var selectedLink = $(this).text();
  $(this).remove();
  $(".more-menu .more").text(selectedLink);
  $(".more-list").toggleClass("open");
  $(".cat-links a").removeClass("active");
  $(".more-menu .more").addClass("active");
});


$(".cat-links a").click(function(){
  $(".categories a").removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

```css
* {
  list-style: none;
  outline: 0;
  border: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  padding:20px;
}


.categories a{
    color: #000;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 16px;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
.categories a:hover{
    opacity: 0.7;
}
.categories a.active{
    opacity: 1;
}
 .categories a.more{
    background: url('../img/down.svg') no-repeat right center;
    padding-right: 14px;
}
 .categories {
    flex: 1;
    display: inline-flex;
    position: relative;
}
 .categories a{
    margin-right: 16px;
}

.more-menu {
  position: relative;
}
.more-list {
    position: absolute;
    right: -80px;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 14px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    top: 30px;
    width: 200px;
    z-index: 999999;
    box-shadow: 0px 32px 84px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08), 0px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06);
    display:none;
}
.more-list.open {
    display:block;
}
.more-list a {
  display: block;
  line-height: 32px;
}
.more-menu .un-more{
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="categories">
  <div class="cat-links">
    <a href="#" class="active">Everything</a>
    <a href="#">Homeware</a>
    <a href="#">Electronics</a>
    <a href="#">Outdoors</a>
    <a href="#">Kids</a>
    <a href="#">Men</a>
    <a href="#">Women</a>
  </div>
  <div class="more-menu">
    <a href="#" class="more">More</a>
    <div class="more-list">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to remove the item from the more list. If you do, you will need to add it again.

```
var moreMenu = $(".cat-links a").slice(3);
$(".cat-links a").slice(3).remove();
$('.more-list').append(moreMenu);

$(".more-menu .more").click(function(){
  $(".more-list").toggleClass("open");
});

$(".more-list a").click(function(){
  var selectedLink = $(this).text();
  $(".more-list a").show(); // show all items
  $(this).hide(); // hide current item
  $(".more-menu .more").text(selectedLink);
  $(".more-list").toggleClass("open");
  $(".cat-links a").removeClass("active");
  $(".more-menu .more").addClass("active");
});


$(".cat-links a").click(function(){
  $(".categories a").removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");
  if (!$(this).hasClass("more")) { // if one of the other links was clicked
    $(".more-list a").show(); // show everything
    $(".more-menu .more").text("More");
  }
});
```

Comment: This one is not slicing the menu items after 3?

Comment: It's just the click events. The rest of your code can stay the same. I've included the full script for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
var moreMenu = $(".cat-links a").slice(3);
$(".cat-links a").slice(3).remove();
$('.more-list').append(moreMenu);

$(".more-menu .more").click(function(){
  $(".more-list").toggleClass("open");
});

$(".more-list a").click(function(){
  var selectedLink = $(this).text();
  $(this).remove(); // you are remove tags 'a' here
  $(".more-menu .more").text(selectedLink);
  $(".more-list").toggleClass("open");
  $(".cat-links a").removeClass("active");
  $(".more-menu .more").addClass("active");
});


$(".cat-links a").click(function(){
  $(".categories a").removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

try to remove this line, `$(this).remove();`, line: 11

Comment: Right, this is not solving the problem. Links under more needs to swap with more, not dissapair. Thanks tho!

Comment: line 11, try to remove it `$(this).remove();`